# How should we have s3fs-fuse connect with TLS1.2?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

We have some legacy EC2 instances that connect to S3 by s3fs-fuse (v1.83 and some).
Now, AWS S3 will force TLS 1.2 or lator by next June, and notified they are still connecting with older TLS versions.

We must configure s3fs to support TLS 1.2 or find other alternatives.

We already read the release notes of s3fs to find nothing about these issues, and the following code shows it has no TLS versions options.
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/blob/master/src/curl.cpp
https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html

Are there any good solutions?

Our environment(just one of the servers):

- OS: Ubuntu 18.x
- s3fs: 1.83

Comment: In the absence of explicit configuration, a modern version of libcurl should automatically be using a sensible, modern TLS version, so there should be no need for s3fs-fuse to specify the version.  Have you confirmed, via the [S3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html) what version is actually being used? And, have you confirmed, via those logs, that it is indeed s3fs-fuse that is connecting to your buckets the old TLS version, and not something else that you are using?  Can you find what version of libcurl your s3fs binaries were compiled against?

Comment: Thanks.Then, should we just configure S3 side by assign  1.2 to "s3:tlsversion"? AWS Health notification says s3fs has connected with older versions, probably based on CloudTrail logs or something.

Comment: *"probably based on CloudTrail logs or something"* Note that I addressed this in my prior comment.  The S3 server access logs will tell you the TLS version for each request, and TLS clients, by default, always use the highest version supported by both client and server.  Read the logs, and you will have the answer.  Configuring your policies to test the [`s3:TlsVersion`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#example-object-tls-version) condition key will deny access to anything using an old version.

Comment: Presently, we have disabled S3 server access logs because it had became too bulky, but will consider to enable temporaly if that tells more. Thanks. APPEND: note that notification did tell s3fs-fuse uses older versions via User-Agent headers.